# Is there a way to merge Excel data that is spread on multiple rows? Is there a better way to represent this data?

Tags: database, excel

I was given a data set that has been set up similar to below. I'm not an expert on managing data sets like this.

```
Col1           Col2             Col3           Col4
ID_ONE         data1            data           data
               data2
               data3
ID_TWO         data             data           data
               data             data           data
ID_THREE       data             data           data
```

The data was provided in an Excel sheet, and ideally all the data would be in one row. But they way it was provided, there are extra rows where they needed to put extra data (one item for each row). In order to analyze and remove unnecessary data, I need them to be in one row. I've seen some ways to concatenate data on Excel, but it's inefficient because they all have differing number of rows. I'd like the extra rows to be inside just one cell, but have a newline character, like so:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

And not

```
data1 data2 data3
```

Is there a web app or alternative way you can see to express the data to make it easier to analyze? I tried to import it into Access but it just made each row a new entry.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean data1, data2 and data3 should be a single row but are on 3 separate rows?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. 3 separate rows but inside one cell. Otherwise I cannot sort the data because it'll think every row is a separate entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the basics of data collection and distribution from many rows to one.

```
Sub collect()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long, vDATAs As Variant
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            ReDim vDATAs(.Columns.Count - 1)
            For rw = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, 1)) Then
                    For cl = 2 To .Columns.Count
                        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then _
                            vDATAs(cl - 2) = .Cells(rw, cl) & _
                                IIf(Len(vDATAs(cl - 2)), Chr(10) & vDATAs(cl - 2), vbNullString)
                    Next cl
                    .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
                Else
                    For cl = 2 To .Columns.Count
                        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then _
                            .Cells(rw, cl) = .Cells(rw, cl) & _
                                IIf(Len(vDATAs(cl - 2)), Chr(10) & vDATAs(cl - 2), vbNullString)
                        vDATAs(cl - 2) = vbNullString
                    Next cl
                End If
            Next rw
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: data_collection_before]    [image: data_collection_after]
               <sup>Sample data before Sub collect</sup>                              <sup>Sample data after Sub collect()</sup>

I'm not sure if this approach is the best method of retaining your data but I do not know enough about what it is used for and the current retrieval methods to make suggestions.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write this up! This is perfect, I just ran the code and it pushed everything together. Now the hard part is to understand what your code is doing. :)